# User Login Block does nothing

Tags: 7, forms, users

The core user login block does not appear to work.

I have it placed in the Header region (Omega theme if that helps), with the following overrides:

```
function mytheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );
   return $hooks;
 }
```

This lets me use my own tpl file for the login block.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_user_login_block(&$vars) {
  $vars['name'] = render($vars['form']['name']);
  $vars['pass'] = render($vars['form']['pass']);
  $vars['submit'] = render($vars['form']['actions']['submit']);
  $vars['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($vars['form']);
}
```

This lets me pass new variables..

Then in the tpl file:

```
<div id="user-login-block-container">
  <div id="user-login-block-form-fields">
    <?php print $name; ?>
    <?php print $pass; ?>
    <?php print $submit; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="/user/register">Create an Account</a> | <a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Except when I login, the page refreshes, and nothing happens. User is not logged in, no error. When I use correct or incorrect credentials, nothing happens.

I used this same approach on a Drupal 6 site and it worked fine. Where am I going wrong?

I disabled Login Destination and Login Toboggan while debugging, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print hidden elements:

```
<div id="user-login-block-container">
  <div id="user-login-block-form-fields">
    <?php print $name; ?>
    <?php print $pass; ?>
    <?php print $submit; ?>
    <?php print $rendered; // HERE HIDDEN ELEMENTS ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="/user/register">Create an Account</a> | <a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>
```